# Get index of an array in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a spectrogram. It's 129 rows x n columns.
I want to "cut" the columns to 20. And I would do something like this:

```
if spectrogram.shape[1] > 20:
                  for row in spectrogram:
                    i = spectrogram.index(row)
                    row = row[:20]
                    spectrogram[i] = row
```

But it throws out an error using `.index()`, so I tried using `.where()` as I saw here on SOF but another error occurred:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where'
```

How should I do?

Comment: Seems like you need basic indexing, here are the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: when it comes to numpy, you have much better choices than iteration. in this case, you can slice like `spectrogram[:, :20]`

Comment: For where do it this way: 'numpy.where(array==item)'

Comment: Thank you guys, gonna accept the answer in the bottom. But your works too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just take the slice you want without the loop (whenever you're tempted to loop over a numpy array, there's usually a better way).

```
spectrogram[:, :20]
```

Here's a simplified example: given a 5x10 array, take just the first 5 of each row giving you a 5x5 array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(50).reshape(5, 10)
a[:, :5]
```

**result**

```
array([
   [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
   [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
   [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]])
```